# Drive to Chimney Rock

Tags: national-parks, north-carolina

I am planning to drive to [Chimney Rock, NC, USA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Chimney+Rock+at+Chimney+Rock+State+Park/@35.4311873,-82.2493577,1427m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xf0c5185c44bc28f!8m2!3d35.4327348!4d-82.2502854). The idea is to drive up to the parking lot next to Cliff Dwellers Gift Shop and walk up to the flag point [shown in this picture](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.4349557,-82.2433925,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPLK0PWeVvn6xZJEWfvIHPO4lLQKqtwqb0g9u_j!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPLK0PWeVvn6xZJEWfvIHPO4lLQKqtwqb0g9u_j%3Dw203-h130-k-no!7i2048!8i1315?shorturl=1).

I want to know:

1. Do you need a 4 wheel drive vehicle to drive to that parking lot?
2. Is that walk/trail ok for a kids stroller and how long is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the satellite view on google maps, you can see lots of normal cars in the parking lot, and the road is paved, so any car can get there (unless there is ice and snow on the road).

The rock is right at the parking lot. There is an elevator that leads up to the rock, but it is out of order and will not be repaired before Thanksgiving 2018. That means you have to walk up the stairs, which is not too bad, but obviously not possible with a stroller.

You can find more details on their website (https://www.chimneyrockpark.com/)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to figure out what cars are there on google maps. How many steps from the parking lot to the rock? I have seen 500 at various places. Is that correct?

Comment: @newton, if you have seen that figure in various places, do you have any reason to believe it might not be true?